# Maximum limit in the length of expression evaluated by eval() in python

Tags: python

Consider the example

```
a = "( False or False )  and  not  ( False and True and False )  and   not  ( False and True and False ) "

print eval(a)

b = "( False or False or False or False or False or False or True or False or False or False or False or False or False or False or False or False or False or False )  and  not False and  not False and  not  ( False and False )  and  not  ( False and False )  and  not  ( False and False )  and  not  ( False and False )  and  not  ( False and False )  and  not  ( False and False )  and  not  ( False and True )  and  not  ( False and False )  and  not  ( False and False )  and  not  ( False and False )  and  not  ( False and False )  and  not  ( False and False) and not False"
print eval(b)
```

First one gives proper output. but for second eventhough synax is correct it is giving

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

because of length. I need to evaluate large expressions in my program. Any suggestions?

Comment: it worked fine in my case. Check your editor setting or try printing b

Comment: More details please ? viz. which version of python are you working on ?

Comment: Works for me, 2.7.9 and 3.4.2. Why don't you just see if you can compute the maximum? b = 'False or False', then try: while True: b.append(b[5:]); eval(b); except SyntaxError....   len(b)

Answer (score 2):

Try to find the limit empirically:

```
b = 'False or False'
while True:
    try:
        b = b + b[5:]
        print len(b), eval(b)
    except:
        print len(b)
        break
```

I stopped it at len(b) == 288MiB. Interestingly, python used up to 5.5GiB of RAM at the 288MiB level.